# Que códigos o webservice para cotação de moedas do Banco Central aceita?

Tags: web-service

Precisei desenvolver uma rotina que pegasse a cotação de venda do dólar e inserisse em uma tabela no banco. O banco central disponibiliza um webservice onde é possível fazer as consultas. Para isso basta informar um código e ele tornar a cotação para você.

O problema que tenho é em conseguir a documentação que informe o que cada código retorna. Não encontrei nada no site do Banco Central. Quais códigos de moeda esse serviço aceita? 
Onde conseguir essa documentação?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Depois de muito pesquisar consegui o código de todas as cotações e resolvi compartilhar aqui.
Antes de chegar na utilização do código, segue o endereço do webservice do BC e a descrição de cada método contido nesse serviço.
O endereço do webservice do banco central é https://www3.bcb.gov.br/sgspub/JSP/sgsgeral/FachadaWSSGS.wsdl

Esse webservice possui os seguintes métodos:

**getUltimoValorVO** - Recupera o último valor de uma determinada série e retorna um objeto do tipo WSSerieVO.

**Parâmetros:**
long codigoSerie – Código da série.
Retorno:
WSSerieVO – Objeto série.

**GetUltimoValorXML** - Recupera o último valor de uma determinada série e retorna o resultado em formato XML.

**Parâmetros:**
long codigoSerie – Código da série.
Retorno:
String – String contendo o resultado da consulta em formato XML.

**getValor** - Recupera o valor de uma série em uma determinada data (dd/MM/aaaa).

**Parâmetros:**
long codigoSerie – Código da série.
String data – String contendo a data (dd/MM/aaaa) do valor a ser pesquisado.
Retorno:
BigDecimal – Objeto contendo o valor.

**getValorEspecial** - Recupera o valor de uma série especial em um período.

**Parâmetros:**
long codigoSerie – Código da série.
String data – String contendo a data (dd/MM/aaaa) inicial.
String dataFim – String contendo a data (dd/MM/aaaa) final.
Retorno:
BigDecimal – Objeto contendo o valor.

**getValoresSeriesXML** - Recupera os valores de uma ou mais séries dentro de um determinado período.O resultado da consulta é devolvido ao cliente em formato XML.

**Parâmetros:**
long[] codigosSeries – Lista(array) dos códigos das séries.
String dataInicio – String contendo a data (dd/MM/aaaa) inicial.
String dataFim – String contendo a data (dd/MM/aaaa) final.
Retorno:
String – String contendo o resultado da consulta em formato XML.

**getValoresSeriesVO** - Recupera os valores de uma ou mais séries dentro de um determinado período e retorna o resultado em forma de Array de objetos do tipo WSSerieVO.

**Parâmetros:**
long[] codigosSeries – Lista(array) dos códigos das séries.
String dataInicio – String contendo a data (dd/MM/aaaa) inicial.
String dataFim – String contendo a data (dd/MM/aaaa) final.
Retorno:
WSSerieVO – Lista(array) de objeto série.

Se você quiser obter a cotação do dia anterior (por exemplo), utilize o método **getUltimoValorVO** que esse método retorna a ultima cotação cadastrada e passe como parâmetro algum dos códigos listados abaixo.

Segue abaixo uma lista com os códigos de cotação.

```
CÓDIGO  NOME
1       Dólar (venda)
10813   Dólar (compra)
21619   Euro (venda)
21620   Euro (compra)
21621   Iene (venda)
21622   Iene (compra)
21623   Libra esterlina (venda)
21624   Libra esterlina (compra)
21625   Franco Suíço (venda)
21626   Franco Suíço (compra)
21627   Coroa Dinamarquesa (venda)
21628   Coroa Dinamarquesa (compra)
21629   Coroa Norueguesa (venda)
21630   Coroa Norueguesa (compra)
21631   Coroa Sueca (venda)
21632   Coroa Sueca (compra)
21633   Dólar Australiano (venda)
21634   Dólar Australiano (compra)
21635   Dólar Canadense (venda)
21636   Dólar Canadense (compra)
```

Caso alguém precise, tenho um [passo a passo](http://blog.tiagocrizanto.com/configuracoes-do-webservice-do-banco-central-cotacoes-diversas/) sobre como gerar uma rotina no SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) para buscar essa cotação e gravar em uma tabela.

## Edit 06-01-2019

Publiquei em meu github outra forma de buscar as cotações utilizando uma aplicação asp net MVC e hangfire para pegar as cotações diariamente.
O código está disponível no [Github](https://github.com/tiagocrizanto/CotacaoDolar) e detalhes sobre como foi feita a implementação está [aqui](http://tiagocrizanto.com/obtendo-cotacao-do-dolar-atraves-de-uma-aplicacao-asp-net-com-hangfire/)

Comment: Legal seria se tu fizesse uma "documentação" e colocasse no GitHub, vai que alguém precisa algum dia?

Comment: Boa ideia! Vou fazer um projeto de exemplo e colocar no GIT. Assim que tiver no jeito coloco o link do repositório aqui.

Answer (score 3):

Eu fiz um loop pelo webservice e salvei em txt o que cada código de cotação representa, não sei se pegou todos mas meu loop foi do 1 ao 50000 e parou de trazer resultados lá pelos 22mil.
Segue o link http://egas.digital/cotacoes.txt